# How to select specific columns from two tables in laravel 7 API?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-query-builder

I am new to Laravel and trying to select specific columns from two different tables using `leftJoin`:

```
public function show(Request $request, Employee $employee)
{
        
  $empno = Employee::find($employee);
  $employees = DB::table('employees')
  ->select('employees.empno','employees.firstname', 'employees.lastname','employee_backgrounds.email','employees.remarks')
  ->leftJoin('employee_backgrounds', 'employees.empno', '=', 'employee_backgrounds.empno')
  ->where('employees.empno', '=', $empno)
  ->get();
  return $employees;
}
```

And here is my request:

```
http://testlaravel.test/api/employees/EMP1987
```

but it returns only:

```
[]
```

any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is wrong.

The first:

```
public function show(Request $request, Employee $employee)
```

It's mean you have a parameter is Employee model. so you can get data from this model, no need to find other:

```
public function show(Request $request, Employee $employee)
{
        
  $employees = DB::table('employees')
  ->select('employees.empno','employees.firstname', 'employees.lastname','employee_backgrounds.email','employees.remarks')
  ->leftJoin('employee_backgrounds', 'employees.empno', '=', 'employee_backgrounds.empno')
  ->where('employees.empno', '=', $employee->empno)
  ->get();
  return $employees;
}
```

The second:

`Employee::find()` acts upon the primary key, if you have set your primary key in your model to something other than id by doing

```
protected  $primaryKey = 'empno';
```

then find will search by that key instead.

So your code maybe:

```
$empno = Employee::find($employee->empno);
```

or

```
$empno = Employee::find($employee->id);
```

For the end, your code maybe like that:

```
public function show(Request $request, Employee $employee)
{
        
  $employees = DB::table('employees')
  ->select('employees.empno','employees.firstname', 'employees.lastname','employee_backgrounds.email','employees.remarks')
  ->leftJoin('employee_backgrounds', 'employees.empno', '=', 'employee_backgrounds.empno')
  ->where('employees.empno', '=', $employee->empno)
  ->get();
  return $employees;
}
```

or

```
public function show(Request $request, int $empno)
{
        
  $employees = DB::table('employees')
  ->select('employees.empno','employees.firstname', 'employees.lastname','employee_backgrounds.email','employees.remarks')
  ->leftJoin('employee_backgrounds', 'employees.empno', '=', 'employee_backgrounds.empno')
  ->where('employees.empno', '=', $empno)
  ->get();
  return $employees;
}
```

or

```
public function show(Request $request, Employee $employee)
{
        
  $empno = Employee::find($employee->empno);
  $employees = DB::table('employees')
  ->select('employees.empno','employees.firstname', 'employees.lastname','employee_backgrounds.email','employees.remarks')
  ->leftJoin('employee_backgrounds', 'employees.empno', '=', 'employee_backgrounds.empno')
  ->where('employees.empno', '=', $empno->empno)
  ->get();
  return $employees;
}
```

If you want to test data, use Laravel Debugbar or dd(); command [dd($empno);]